# Ruby servers and CGI

Tags: ruby, webserver, cgi

I've used Apache for some projects, but I've never really dug deep into it.(or any server for that matter) Recently I started reading more about servers, how they are built, ect.

The servers which I've looked up (in ruby) such as [goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath) or [thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/) show off their request handling mechanisms [example](https://gist.github.com/igrigorik/845866). They don't seem to show off their CGI capabilities, which I've used a lot so far. This got me thinking the following things:

- Is CGI supported by all 'major' (or serious) servers (for example the ones mentioned above) ?
- How common is it to not use CGI and just some complex logic in the request handling ? If it is common is it used in serious projects or just small ones ?
- Is the CGI support something that must be enabled by the user or is it set up by default ? I realise that this question is complex, but we are talking about the general case here. (For example apache has a CGI-bin by default + it has a config file where you can set up additional directories)

I realize that  this question contains a coupple of questions inside of it, however due to them being closely related I think that it doesn't violate the "one question per thread" rule of this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGI is a dead technology that isn't really used by anyone in a serious capacity. Since it depends on spinning up a process to handle each request, it's woefully inefficient. In the 1990s before replacement technologies like [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) or Apache httpd modules that embed the language, like [mod_perl](https://perl.apache.org/), [mod_php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php) or [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) for Ruby supplanted it.

CGI is still supported in Apache httpd if you configure it, and the default configuration often has it enabled, but it should be turned off for security reasons. There's no reason for it in 2014.

The more modern strategy is to use Apache httpd or nginx as a proxy to one or more persistent, HTTP capable processes. This is much more efficient than spinning up a CGI process, handling one request, and shutting it down.